# MPI on Ubuntu Hello World Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, ubuntu, mpi

I'm trying to run a basic MPI example from http://condor.cc.ku.edu/~grobe/docs/intro-MPI-C.shtml

In a fresh Ubuntu, I run:
apt-get install vim gcc libcr-dev mpich2 mpich2-doc

and put

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int ierr;

  ierr = MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  printf("Hello world\n");

  ierr = MPI_Finalize();
}
```

into hello.c.
Then I run

```
$ mpicc hello.c -o hello
```

and

```
$ mpirun -np 4 hello
```

So, just like in the example.
Instead of the expected output, I get:

```
Segmentation fault
```

I already looked a lot in the net, but for MPI you cannot find a lot.
Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you need to pass argv as a value/copy?

Comment: Your piece of code works fine : i am not able to reproduce the segmentation fault. And your code seems correct.

Comment: try `mpirun -np 4 ./hello`

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answers so far, but it still doesn't work. I'm trying to get this working with Docker, what you can perfectly reproduce: [Docker Image at Github](https://github.com/kitedu/programming-paradigms/tree/master/MPI) (there is also a description how to run the the Docker Image)